# SQL: shopping cart design for a marketplace

Tags: mysql, sql, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I'm working on a marketplace that requires the user to be logged in to add items to the shopping cart. In most online examples, I can't see the benefits of creating a separate `cart` and `cart_item` tables.

Example: https://mysql.tutorials24x7.com/blog/guide-to-design-database-for-shopping-cart-in-mysql

Why not just create an empty `order` and set its `status` to `cart` and when the user submits the `order`, then just reduce the quantities from the `product` table and fill the other columns with the required values and change the `status` of the `order`?

Example with shopping cart
[image]

Example using the `order` table to act as a cart when setting its `status` to `cart`.
[image]

Comment: Yep, that could work.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the comment. But which one the better approach? What I'm missing here?

Comment: It probably depends on your specific needs, but other things being equal, I'd probably go with the second model - although I wouldn't use `order` as a table name.

Comment: Incidentally, the datatype for price wouldn't normally be int. Nor would it be float, as you link suggests. DECIMAL exists for a reason. And just to observe, `order_item.price` is usually only established at the point the order is actually placed.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry! About the price datatype, I'm using `decimal` and these are just quick examples to clarify the question. And yes, `order_item.price` would only be established at the purchase time.

Comment: One of the possible reasons to have `cart` and `order` as separate entities: user can add something to cart, but do not want to order it right now, just save for later. So he or she selects items to order from the cart and proceeds to checkout. After that all other items are accessible via cart and not some cumbersome lists (like favourites or 'saved items'). I like stores working this way, it is really handy.

Comment: Apart from 'saved for later order' there may be different deliveries to different addresses: some items should be delivered to my home address, some of them should be delivered to my work address, because they will be available earlier and more critical to have, some may be a gift and should be delivered to another town. Clicking the same items multiple times just to combine them to different orders (without cart as separate entity) is too boring

Comment: Hi @Strawberry, could you please check this question on DBA https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/284883/sql-shopping-cart-design-for-a-multi-vendor-marketplace

Comment: Yep; we can go through it all again there.